# WKHTTPCookieStore not retrieving set Cookie.

Tags: ios11, wkwebview, nshttpcookie, wkhttpcookiestore

I'm trying to set a cookie programmatically but it's not working. The cookie gives the impression that it's valid. I then set it on the `WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore`. In the asynchronous call back I then try to get all the cookies out of the store. However, my cookie isn't there. Where's it gone!?

```
    let httpCookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore

    var cookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]()
    cookieProperties[.name] = "MarkCookie"
    cookieProperties[.value] = "MarkValue"
    cookieProperties[.domain] = "localhost"
    cookieProperties[.maximumAge] = 1234
    cookieProperties[.path] = "/"

    let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)!

    httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
        // This is called fine. The cookie looks ok. 
        print("Cookie set \(cookie)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
                // This is empty!!!!
                print(cookies)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this still an issue with iOS 11.4? In my tests it was necessary to also specify the originURL, but my problem was somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing `setCookie` and was receiving a vexing `NetworkProcessProxy::didClose` “crash” message on the console for every cookie I set (though, my app, itself, was not actually crashing). And a fetch of `getAllCookies` (or the `async` method, `allCookies`, in my case) was returning an empty array.

So, wondering if the problem was in `getAllCookies`, I decided to actually open a `WKWebView` so I could see if the cookies were actually being delivered (i.e., trying to determine if the problem was the cookies themselves, or some idiosyncratic API behavior). But as soon as I actually had my `WKWebView` load the page in question, all subsequent `setCookie` calls were successful, as were my calls to `getAllCookies`/`allCookies`.

I haven't tracked it down entirely, but it looks like there is some WebKit initialization that needs to happen, something resolved by loading the `WKWebView`, if nothing else. The challenge is that while I was previously stymied, not getting past this error, now that I have successfully loading a `WKWebView`, I can no longer reproduce the error. (I have tried emptying the “derived data” folder, attempting in a new project or new domain, manually deleting the stored data for that domain in Safari, etc. None of these reproduce the error.) Lol.